# How do I find input impedance here?

Tags: input-impedance

[image: Electrical Engineering Finding input impedance]
I'm not too sure how to go about doing this. Added what I did so far but I don't know where I messed up.[image: My solution part 1]
[image: My solution part 2]

Comment: This looks like homework so you need to show some effort at a solution to prevent your question being closed as off-topic as we don't offer a free homework service. Use the edit link below your question.

Comment: Working on it now! Sorry, new to this site :)

Comment: What made you think you messed up?

Answer (score 0):

I would do mesh analysis and put the final equation into the form Z = V/I and pick out the Z. Be careful of the meshes you pick though. If you pick the wrong one you end up with an recursion of infinite substitutions for Vx. I got the same answer you did.